# Split an existing indexed array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

Im Attempting to read a .txt file that is seperated by commas and two lines, currently i have it setup so that it reads the txt file but having trouble with using the.split method with the taxArray, i need to use the .split so i can calulate the differnt values.

```
string[] taxArray = new string[2];
int count = 0;

try
{
    if(File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        //read the lines from text file add each line to its own array index.
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            taxArray[count] = line;
            txtDisplay.Text += taxArray[count] + "\r\n";
            count++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This file cannot be found");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

This currently outputs exactly as i need.

Comment: "...having trouble with it ..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: all im asking for basically is information on how to use .split method in order to split an existing array, the above is my current progress on the first half of my mini project.

Comment: In the above code, where do you have problem? What problem? What is the expected output? You are not describing your problem. Your comments in code says its doing what you wanted, so where is the problem?

Comment: so you are wanting to `split` an `array`?  if so you may want to explain more...

Comment: Yeah, so far i've managed to set up and array to have the first line and second line indexed, now i need to use the. .split command to separate the values in the array and index them in their own arrays which i believe is what happens if i managed to figure out how to use the .split method, sorry for the vague explanations first time using this platform.

Comment: taxArray[i].Split(...)?

Comment: Thanks Tobias, Somehow i managed with very little to go on here was my answer in the end string[] incomeBracket = taxArray[1].Split(',');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my solution, I was calling to the array before the foreach loop did its job reading the txt file, thanks for the assistance Toby <3

```
string[] taxArray = new string[2];
            int count = 0;
            // string incomeBracket = taxArray[0];

            //string[] incomeBracketArray = incomeBracket.Split(',');

            try
            {
                if(File.Exists(filePath))
                {

                    //read the lines from text file add each line to its own array index.
                    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        taxArray[count] = line;
                        txtDisplay.Text += taxArray[count] + "\r\n";
                        count++;
                    }
                    string[] incomeBracket = taxArray[1].Split(',');
                    txtDisplay.Text = incomeBracket[0];

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This file cannot be found");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```